# Export SSL certificates from Chrome for Android

Tags: chrome-for-android, certificates, export

I have a Nexus 5 with the latest Android 4.4.2. I'm registered on using Chrome. They use client certificates to authenticate the user. I installed the certificate and could successfully use the site on my mobile. However, now I want to use the site on my laptop, but Chrome does not seem to sync these certificates.

I did not find an option in Chrome on my mobile regarding certificates. I also could not find anything in `Settings` > `Security` > `Trusted credentials`

Is it possible to export these client certificates from my Android device, so I can import and use them on my laptop?

Comment: If you root the device and get a prompt, you should be able to just search the entire device for a .crt in what looks to be a Chrome path, no? For a non-rooted device, using only stock functionality, I'm almost sure you cannot do this.

Answer (score 3):

Just faced with exactly the same problem. I googled for an answer but this is page the only case I found.

Solution is simple for *rooted* device:

1. Open and file explorer with root-access (I prefer ES file explorer)
2. Go to `/data/misc/keystore/usesr_0` and find there the cert and key files.
3. Transfer it securely to your desktop.

If you have a non-rooted device then root it and start with step <1>.